# Could not get unknown property 'repositoryUrl' for project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project employing React-Native. I'm [building the RN module from source](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-building-from-source.html), so my project has the ReactAndroid module as a dependency.

I was trying to upgrade the project to Android gradle build tools >=2.3.2, so I could use instant-run:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        ...
    }
}
```

This change forced me to upgrade gradle itself from 3.1 to 3.5 (latest stable).

Building the project suddenly produces the following gradle error

> Could not get unknown property 'repositoryUrl' for project
> ':ReactAndroid' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, this turned out interesting.

## The reason

The error pointed to the this line at the React-Native module's `release.gradle`:

```
def getRepositoryUrl() {
    return hasProperty('repositoryUrl')  ? property('repositoryUrl') : 'https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/'
}
```

Strangely enough, the problem is that `hasProperty('repositoryUrl')` returns `true`, while `property('repositoryUrl')` causes the error.

On gradle 3.1, `hasProperty('repositoryUrl')` returns `false`.

Apparently in gradle 3.5, `hasProperty()` returns `true` in cases where the property is indeed missing but still has a getter. In our case the getter is

```
def getRepositoryUrl() {...}
```

This is vaguely explained [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#properties).

There is however another method of checking for properties, which ignores getters, named [findProperty](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#findProperty(java.lang.String)).

## The fix

So the fix was to change the following block from `release.gradle`:

```
def getRepositoryUrl() {
    return hasProperty('repositoryUrl') ? property('repositoryUrl') : 'https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/'
}

def getRepositoryUsername() {
    return hasProperty('repositoryUsername') ? property('repositoryUsername') : ''
}

def getRepositoryPassword() {
    return hasProperty('repositoryPassword') ? property('repositoryPassword') : ''
}
```

To this:

```
def getRepositoryUrl() {
    return findProperty('repositoryUrl') != null ? property('repositoryUrl') : 'https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/'
}

def getRepositoryUsername() {
    return findProperty('repositoryUsername') !=null ? property('repositoryUsername') : ''
}

def getRepositoryPassword() {
    return findProperty('repositoryPassword') != null ? property('repositoryPassword') : ''
}
```

More pains experienced while building the RN module from source [here](http://www.devsbedevin.net/the-pains-of-building-android-react-native-from-source/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could be better to use the function **hasProperty** of project instead.
Like following:

```
def getRepositoryUrl() {
    return project.hasProperty('repositoryUrl') ? property('repositoryUrl') : 'https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/'
}

def getRepositoryUsername() {
    return project.hasProperty('repositoryUsername') ? property('repositoryUsername') : ''
}

def getRepositoryPassword() {
    return project.hasProperty('repositoryPassword') ? property('repositoryPassword') : ''
}
```

The problem is caused by upgrading gradle from 2.x to 3.x. So I find that higher version of react-native such as 0.57.4 has above script in ReactAndroid/release.gradle and it works out.